# Weird bug with switching string in map-reduce java

Tags: java, string, hadoop, mapreduce

So I have this **Reduce** function:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (Text value: values){
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(value.toString());
        String name = matrix.get_name(); // Return "A" or "B"
        context.write(key, new Text(name));
    }
```

}

Executing this block of code gave me something like (which makes sense):

```
0,0 A
0,1 A
...
0,0 B
...
```

Then when I tried switching the value of "name":

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (Text value: values){
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(value.toString());
        String name = matrix.get_name(); // Return "A" or "B"
        switch (name){
            case "A":
                context.write(key, new Text("AA"));
                break;
            case "B":
                context.write(key, new Text("BB"));
                break;
            default:
                context.write(key, new Text("CC"));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code gave me this result:

```
0,0 CC
0,1 CC
...
```

What I do not understand is why my switch statement does work in this case (using equals to compare does not work either)

Any pointers to solve this problem?

Your help will be appreciated.

// Updated:

Using trim() and equalsIgnoreCase() do not work either:

```
if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(name.trim())){
    context.write(key, new Text("AA"));
}
else if ("B".equalsIgnoreCase(name.trim())){
    context.write(key, new Text("BB"));
}
else{
    context.write(key, new Text("CC"));
}
```

Comment: It would be best to use if else and equals instead of switch statement to ensure compiler will use equals methos to compare strings. I would also recommend trim() and equalsIgnoreCase() if case is not important. Also print the output to see why it is does not equal to your A or B.

Comment: @KillerDeath you should write that as the answer, because it's almost certainly correct.

Comment: Yes, it has to be that, not many options here, thx for advice

Comment: try to print hex code of name.charAt(0), maybe it not really 'A'

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare strings using switch statement, use trim() and equalsIgnoreCase() in that order combined with if else, of course.

```
if(name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("A"){...}

else if name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("B"){...}
else ...
```

Comment: When name should be for example "A", print it so that we see what it is. Does appropriate "if" trigger a breakpoint?